# How does InnoDB represent composite integer keys?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, clustered-primary-key

Let's say I have the following table:

```
Create Table Orders(server : tiny int, ticket : integer, primary key (server, ticket));
```

How is the composite primary key representation when stored on disk?

1. `server * 2^32 + ticket` (a numeric composition of the two keys)
2. `server & " " & ticket` (a string concatenation of the two attributes)
3. Something entirely different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InnoDB uses [B+Tree](http://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/10/btree-index-structures-in-innodb/) to store indexes and tables (the entire table is stored *inside* its primary key) and it stores the multiple columns as [tuples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) (ordered lists) so actually there is somewhere an equivalent to a *tree node* having two properties - `server` and `ticket` both separate numbers.

The entire tree is then a way to store an ordered list of such pairs/tuples - they are ordered first by the first column (`server`) and in case of a tie the second columns (`ticket`) are compared and decide the ordering. For the *primary key* there should be no ties on both columns because it is *unique*, but for *non-unique* composite indexes there might be. But in InnoDB each secondary index has the *primary key* columns added to it (because the *primary key* is the pointer to actual data row) so any ties in there can be solved by ordering on the added *primary key* columns.

If you want to imagine it, then take a phonebook - each row consists of three values `(lastName, firstName, phoneNumber)` and is sorted in that order - the ordering might be effectively equivalent to `lastName & " " & firstName` but it is really done *piecewise*.